# Software for tracking the changes within a folder?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, linux-distribution, operating-system, performance-testing

I'm trying to decide on a Linux distro to put onto a USB, and use as a portable "computer". One of the main factors in deciding on said Distro is how much it writes to the USB during regular use. So I plan on using VirtualBox to test out some OSs, can anybody recommend me a software that can tell me how much activity goes on within the folder that I allocate as the OS's Virtual Hard Drive? (I also want to use this to compare software that I will be using inside the OS)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As that most likely shall be evaluated on the host: what OS is the host running? Also, if it comes to paid software, how much you'd be willing to spend?